# Can we have a "show only favorite tags" option?

Tags: feature-request, watched-tags

On Stack Overflow, there is no option to show only favorite tags. The reason for that is given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions/63947#63947):

> We believe that browsing by tag, and tag combination, should be sufficient. The bleedthrough and forced exposure to other topics is intentional; we believe programmers have more in common across languages and disciplines than they think they do. We don't want to create more "ghettos" where programmers only care about or look at certain pet topics.
>
> Good programmers are well-rounded, and are aware of the world outside their "special preferred" tag.

That reasoning doesn't hold up so well on Gaming. If I'm really into, say, *Fallout: New Vegas*, it's not going to help me "develop my craft" to see questions about *World of Warcraft*. It'll be a lot easier for me — and, I think, everyone else — to list a few games I *am* interested in than to list every single game I'm *not* interested in. Fortunately, since we tag with game names here, this comes down to a tag handling tweak. Can we get a "show only favorite tags" feature to supplement the "hide ignored tags" feature?

And yes, I know, as an engine-related question, this really belongs on Meta Stack Overflow, but I thought I'd gauge interest here before I brought it up there.

Answer (score 4):

If you add the following lines to a user style sheet for this site, you should see only questions in your tags.

```
.question-summary {
    display: none;
}
.tagged-interesting {
    display: block;
}
```

Note that they'll need to appear in that order so that the later rule supersedes the earlier one. (You could also add `!important` to the tagged-interesting rule.) Of course, this won't change the question counts, and you may actually see some pages with no questions at all, but you should be able to page back and forth as you normally would. This also won't affect questions in the sidebar; those have no identifying characteristics (other than question number) and thus can't be filtered in a similar fashion client-side.

Comment: This works great with stylish - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

Comment: Yeah, that's what I used to test them, but I wanted to make the answer more generic for those using different browsers. Then again, I see it's available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and [SeaMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/seamonkey/downloads/latest/2108/addon-2108-latest.xpi?src=search) ...

Answer (score 2):

> This answer posted for the benefit of people who don't dig around on Meta as much. I'm sorry, @Pop, nothing to see here, move along.
>
> ---

I've done a little digging on MSO, and saw your question has already been asked here:

> [**Tab for interesting questions**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions)
>
> Why don't we have a Tab that shows only questions for our interesting tags, showing recent first? I keep having to scroll down the page to find the questions I'm interested in.
>
> <sub>[Lance Roberts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts)</sub>

This was marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) with [the following explanation:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions/63947#63947)

> We believe that browsing by tag, and tag combination, should be sufficient. The bleedthrough and forced exposure to other topics is intentional; we believe programmers have more in common across languages and disciplines than they think they do. We don't want to create more "ghettos" where programmers only care about or look at certain pet topics.
>
> <sub>[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)</sub>

To browse by tag, merely click on the relevant tag; click on a tag in the sidebar to refine the view. Alternatively, use the search box: `[foo] [bar]` will only show questions tagged foo *and* bar.

---

In alternative, there's this other question:

[**Filter view to show only interested**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested)

marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) with Jeff's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested/79451#79451):

> Great suggestion! This was ultimately implemented, but only for Stack Overflow at the moment due to the huge ~2.5k questions per day volume.
>
> [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)
>
> <sub>[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)</sub>

That's not *exactly* what you're asking for, as it merely bumps questions with interesting tags up while digging questions with ignored tags down; you however still have the chance to see *all* questions.

Also, it's enabled on all sites, it's just not linked to:

> #### https://gaming.stackexchange.com/?tab=interesting

It's really not an improvement on this particular site, but it's there if you like it better.

Comment: The first post in your answer is the exact same one I quoted and linked in my question; oversight on your part, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lord Have you read my disclaimer at the top? I started writing the answer assuming the asker was a normal user without much time to surf MSO; I only noticed it was _you_ of all people when I was almost done... I posted it anyway for the benefit of the "regulars"

Comment: I did, but it still seems unnecessary to me. Nothing to fight over, though. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of afraid that would be more depressing than anything...

[image]

Comment: Screenshot is kind of old but still.

Comment: but that's only questions with *no upvoted* answer, while one might be interested in questions *with* upvoted answers which one might have wondered about before but didn't remember to ask

Comment: @Tobias, I'm not saying that page is what he is looking for.